# Project Euler #329 (Prime Frog) - Stochastic independence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence, project-euler

> Susan has a prime frog.
> Her frog is jumping around over 500 squares numbered 1 to 500. He can only jump one square to the left or to the right, with equal probability, and he cannot jump outside the range [1;500].
> (if it lands at either end, it automatically jumps to the only available square on the next move.)
>
> When he is on a square with a prime number on it, he croaks 'P' (PRIME) with probability 2/3 or 'N' (NOT PRIME) with probability 1/3 just before jumping to the next square.
> When he is on a square with a number on it that is not a prime he croaks 'P' with probability 1/3 or 'N' with probability 2/3 just before jumping to the next square.
>
> Given that the frog's starting position is random with the same probability for every square, and given that she listens to his first 15 croaks, what is the probability that she hears the sequence PPPPNNPPPNPPNPN?
>
> Give your answer as a fraction p/q in reduced form.

My idea is this:

First calculate $P_n$ = $P\text{("frog sits on a prime after }n\text{ jumps")}$, which can be done by some basic combinatorics + evaluating the "ribbon". I got

\begin{equation}
P_0 = 19/100 = 95/500, P_1 = 24/125, P_2 = 571/3000, \dots
\end{equation}

which should be ok.

Next, for $n=0,\dots,14$ calculate

\begin{equation}
Q_n = P_n \cdot P(\text{"sits on $P$ and croaks }X_n\text{"}) + (1 - P_n) \cdot P(\text{"sits on $N$ and croaks }X_n\text{"})
\end{equation}

where $(X_n)_{n=0\dots14} = PPPPNNPPPNPPNPN$ is our croaking sequence and

\begin{equation}
  P(\text{"sits on $X$ and croaks }Y\text{"})=\begin{cases}
    1/3, & \text{if $X\dot{\lor}Y$}.\\
    2/3, & \text{else}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

That is, $Q_n$ should exactly be $P(\text{"}n\text{th croak equals }X_n\text{"})$ and the product of the $Q_n$ should be the solution. But it's not, so where am I wrong? Are the $Q_n$ not stochastically independent? Whether the frog croaked $P$ or $N$ after $n$ steps should not affect the probability for him to croak $X_{n+1}$ next!?

My results are

\begin{equation}
119/300\text{ for $X = P$ (should be correct)}\\
17731/112500\text{ for $X = PP$ (should actually be $173/1125$ I think)}\\
\dots
\end{equation}

Comment: I would write a program which computes probabilities of the given sequence of croaks for each of 500 starting points and take average.

Comment: Brute force would take like 8 Mio. steps, I'm looking for something a bit more efficient ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a contest question.

Comment: And it seems to be much more complicated to tweak the naive approach, caching f.e.

Comment: @heropup What kind of contest you're talking about? It's a simple question by a simple guy who likes to get his head around some neat little problem. No fame or money included... so why the downvote?

Comment: @DonFuchs The point of Project Euler is to **learn how to solve the problems yourself,** not to have other people solve them for you.  Asking for outside help just so that you can increase your rank on the site is discouraged.

Comment: @heropup I tried it and I'm stuck. I may try the rest of my life and fail, or I may as well ask for **some advice** (nothing more) and learn something new. That's the point of ProjectEuler and every other maths problem. But today all has to be about ranks and credit of course.

Comment: I doubt that computationally efficient solution exists. Are you sure that the problem is not a plain programming problem?

Comment: Usually it's applying math to reduce a problem from "takes years to run when programming the naive approach" to "takes minutes to run when progtamming using ther math". This one seems to actually already be in the form that the naive brute force approch is doable. $500\times2^{15}\approx 16.3$ million steps is "nothing" for Euler problems and also nothing for modern computers. The high number of correct solutions seems to support that this is an easy problem.

Comment: @Ingix $16.3$ million may be doable, but that's not the point. I do not care about efficiency to reduce execution time, it's all about improving my programming skills as well as applying my (obviously inadequate) maths skills. And I think this is also in the spirit of PE to even tackle the simplest of questions with brains rather than brute force.

Comment: Right. Now a few people have told you that they don't see a way to significantly reduce the problem. I tried to point where your errors are in the my answer below. Maybe there is a way to attack the problem mathematically without brute force? I don't see it, a few others here don't see it. Maybe someone will see it and make an answer: Great, then we all will have learned something. In  the mean time, **my** opinion is that this is a problem that is easily solvable with brute force and no such matematical simplification exist. The 16 mio. steps just confirm the brute force approach works.

Comment: This whole discussion is kind of frustrating. I was expecting insights on a plain mathematical problem. What I got so far is **don't cheat, do it by yourself** and **what's the point of thinking if we have fast machines** (no offense guys)

Comment: What you got is "This is a programming problem that (according to the people here) **does not have a mathematical solution**". You simply picked the wrong problem in the hopes to apply some math. It seems to be of no use here.

Comment: There are lots of other Euler problems that actually need to apply some maths to reduce the problem to something that can be done with brute force or rather an algoritm that has an acceptable running time. Again, it seems you have by bad luck picked the wrong problem to apply the skills you want to apply.

Comment: @Ingix How can a number problem (solved by a computer) not have a mathematical solution?? It's only maths inside, the computer is only doing maths. You can find highly sophisticated maths inside the dumbest of mathematical (or programming) problems.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your $P_n$ calculation for $n=0,1$, so let's assume it's correct. Your main error is that the events "frog sits on a prime after n jumps" and therefore the event $Q_n$ describes are highly correlated for consecutive $n$.

After all, if the frog is on a prime number after n steps, this is highly likely an odd number. After one more jump it is then higly likely on an even number, which in turn is highly likely not $2$, so not a prime number. So the frog being on a prime before and after a jump is highly unlikely (just $2 \leftrightarrow 3$)

You approach might work if it was an "odd/even" Frog, that croaks differently based on if the number it's on is odd/even. Then you know for a fact that the Frog will alternate beween an odd and an even postition. But with prime numbers and their irregurities, you cannot hope to describe the differences between how prime numbers are distributed near one prime and another.

Comment: I agree that the $P_n$ events are highly correlated. But for the $Q_n$ events, is it not like throwing a dice: no matter how many 1s I've thrown before, the prop. to throw 1 next will always be 1/6.
No matter how often the frog has croaked P in the past, the prop. of the next P should only depend on the frogs position

Comment: To be more precise: that the frog did just croak P does not say anything about his position; he could have sit on a prime or not.

Comment: Exactly. But still you repeatedly use events like "frog sits on a prime after n jumps" when you have no idea what that probability is under the condition that the frog did the croaks he made before. What you are calculating is probabilities for a game where after each croak the frog is not jumping left or right, but randomly placed on primes or not primes according to your probability $P_n$. This is only the correct probability if you have no further information. ...

Comment: But now you have, the frog did croak previously, so the probability that it was on certain numbers is a posteriori different from what you assumed when calculating P_n. You can check this for just the croak sequence "P", for example. After the initial "P" croak, the probability  for frog to be after his first jump in any of the 500 possible postions is no longer the same as you assumed, because the frog was mor likely to have started from a prime than you assumed.

Comment: Thanks, I got it... so the $Q_n$ are independent, but my calculation of $Q_n$ is wrong as $P_n$ is not independent of the previous croaks...?! That's a start, I got to think about it.